# I want to scrape the web, but the The html code can't be found

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hello iam beginer in scraping website. I hope someone can help me.
I want to **scrape** website from https://www.bhinneka.com/jual?cari=iphone about the item sell and the price can't be found when iam parsing them.

I write the code below :

```
import bs4
import requests
url = 'http://www.bhinneka.com/jual?cari=iphone'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
produk = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'product-title'})
```

thank you so much for helping me

Comment: Read up about selenium, that page use ajax, and beautifulsoup alone can't execute the JS code

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded from external URL via Ajax. You can use `requests` module to load it, for example:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://api.bhinneka.com/gws/graphql"

payload = {
    "operationName": "getSearchPageData",
    "query": 'query getSearchPageData($keyword: String, $page: Int, $range: String, $sort: String, $filter: String) {\n  search(\n    include: "category,brand,price,shippingMethod,merchant,storeCity"\n    keyword: $keyword\n    page: $page\n    limit: 40\n    filter: $filter\n    range: $range\n    aggs: "variants.activePrice"\n    sort: $sort\n    exclude: ""\n  ) {\n    code\n    success\n    message\n    meta {\n      took\n      totalRecords\n      totalPages\n      limit\n      page\n      aggregation {\n        price {\n          min\n          max\n          __typename\n        }\n        brand {\n          id\n          name\n          slug\n          count: docCount\n          __typename\n        }\n        intervalPrice {\n          start\n          count: docCount\n          __typename\n        }\n        shipping: shippingMethod {\n          code\n          name\n          count: docCount\n          __typename\n        }\n        location: storeCity {\n          id\n          name\n          count: docCount\n          __typename\n        }\n        categories: category {\n          ...FilterCategory\n          children: child {\n            ...FilterCategory\n            children: child {\n              ...FilterCategory\n              children: child {\n                ...FilterCategory\n                __typename\n              }\n              __typename\n            }\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        merchant {\n          id\n          name\n          count: docCount\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    result {\n      merchant {\n        name\n        vanityUrl\n        storeDistrict {\n          name\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      description\n      isPreOrder\n      durationPreOrder\n      productWarranty\n      isSold\n      name\n      image {\n        small\n        thumbnail\n        __typename\n      }\n      media {\n        variant {\n          name\n          thumbnail\n          small\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      brand {\n        id\n        name\n        __typename\n      }\n      category {\n        id\n        name\n        __typename\n      }\n      variants {\n        promoPrice {\n          percentage\n          nominal\n          specialPrice\n          startDate\n          endDate\n          __typename\n        }\n        id\n        skuInternal\n        name\n        fullName\n        slug\n        nameVariantMedia\n        stockAvailable\n        stockMinimum\n        priceAfterTax\n        priceNormal\n        isActive\n        sellingPrice\n        activePrice\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment FilterCategory on AggrCategoryType {\n  id\n  name\n  slug\n  level: category\n  count: docCount\n  __typename\n}\n',
    "variables": {
        "filter": "variants.isActive:true,isSold:true,merchant.isActive:true",
        "keyword": "iphone",  # <-- change keyword here
        "range": "",
        "sort": "",
    },
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for r in data["data"]["search"]["result"]:
    print(r["name"])
```

Prints:

```
Ferrari - Power Case iPhone 11 Pro Max 6.5 Full Cover - Powerbank 4000 mAh
Ferrari - Power Case iPhone 11 Pro Max 6.5 Full Cover - Powerbank 4000 mAh
CASEOLOGY Parallax for iPhone X/ iPhone Xs
CASEOLOGY Waterfall Series for iPhone 7/ iPhone 8
PROTEGO Back Protector for iPhone 7 / iPhone 8
PROTEGO Tempered Glass for Apple iPhone 7 / iPhone 8
SPIGEN iPhone Stand S315
VIVAN Paket Fast Charging iPhone VIVAN Charger USB 3.0 + Kabel iPhone
APPLE iPhone 11
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12
APPLE iPhone 12 Pro
APPLE iPhone 12 Pro
APPLE iPhone 12 Pro
APPLE iPhone 12 mini
APPLE iPhone 12 mini
APPLE iPhone 12 mini
APPLE iPhone 12 mini
APPLE iPhone 12 mini
APPLE iPhone 12 mini
APPLE iPhone SE 2020
APPLE iPhone SE 2020
APPLE iPhone SE 2020
APPLE iPhone SE 2020
APPLE iPhone SE 2020
APPLE iPhone SE 2020
APPLE USB Adaptor Charger iPhone
Ailun Screen Protector for iPhone X
INDOSCREEN Anti Break Apple iPhone 11
PROTEGO Tempered Glass iPhone 6 - 6s
PROTEGO Tempered Glass for iPhone XR
CAPDASE Crystal Jacket for iPhone X
```

Answer (score 0):

The response object is being passed instead of the content: `soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")`.

For reference: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content